# Python Concatenate Multiple CSV files with no header

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have about 3,000 csv files and they are all named differently. Example, CDEE.csv and the structure is just one line containing the name and an amount.

```
CDEE | 3993
```

I tried to concatenate and I keep getting

```
CDEE | 3993 | AASE| 3939 .........
```

but I want

```
CDEE | 3992
AASE | 3939
xxxx | yyyy
```

Here is the code:
    import pandas as pd
    import glob, os

```
path = "/home/username/myfolder" 
os.chdir(path)
results = pd.DataFrame([])

for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob(".csv*")):
    namedf = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows=0, usecols=[1,2,3])
    results = results.append(namedf)

results.to_csv('Combined.csv')
```

Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Are you actually doing anything with the DataFrame or just purely wanting to concat the files? As `cat *.csv > csv_files.all` is looking pretty promising right now...

Comment: I didn't see that until I edited the post.  I'm with you.

Comment: @JonClements you should write that as an answer...

Comment: whoa, I'm trying now!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `pd.concat` which is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

path = "."
os.chdir(path)
results = pd.DataFrame()

for counter, current_file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
    namedf = pd.read_csv(current_file, header=None, sep="|")
    print(namedf)
    results = pd.concat([results, namedf])

results.to_csv('Combined.csv', index=None, header=None, sep="|")
```

Note that there are few mistakes to fix:

- change `glob.glob(".csv*")` to `glob.glob("*.csv")` to get all files that end with `.csv`
- to get exactly the following output:

```
CDEE|3992
AASE|3939
xxxx|yyyy
```

You need to call `df.to_csv` with `index=None` to not write the index, `header=None` to not write the header and `sep="|"` to use `|` as separator instead of the default `,`